# How does mongo filter nested arrays in an array

Tags: mongodb

How does mongo filter nested arrays in an array?

document:

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "63c624a47bcab502a2dd58ac"
  },
  "frontId": "0315",
  "cloudDictValue": "80",
  "cloudDictLabel": "",
  "cloudDictCode": "471807045969776640",
  "gatewayTreeResp": [
    {
      "frontId": "005",
      "gatewayDictValue": "90",
      "gatewayDictLabel": "",
      "gatewayDictCode": "471807606496563200",
      "noStationTreeResp": [
        {
          "frontId": "000",
          "typeDictValue": "5950",
          "typeDictLabel": "",
          "typeDictCode": "453008915757404160",
          "entities": []
        },
        {
          "frontId": "001",
          "typeDictValue": "2013",
          "typeDictLabel": "",
          "typeDictCode": "453384258666237952",
          "entities": []
        },
        {
          "frontId": "002",
          "typeDictValue": "2401",
          "typeDictLabel": "",
          "typeDictCode": "453397537065144320",
          "entities": []
        },
        {
          "frontId": "003",
          "typeDictValue": "2400",
          "typeDictLabel": "",
          "typeDictCode": "454775582300704768",
          "entities": []
        },
        {
          "frontId": "004",
          "typeDictValue": "2500",
          "typeDictLabel": "",
          "typeDictCode": "472806363262488576"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

the first array can filter use $filter but nested array how to filter?

how to filter gatewayDictValue=90 and typeDictValue=5950?

expect document:

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "63c624a47bcab502a2dd58ac"
  },
  "frontId": "0315",
  "cloudDictValue": "80",
  "cloudDictLabel": "",
  "cloudDictCode": "471807045969776640",
  "gatewayTreeResp": [
    {
      "frontId": "005",
      "gatewayDictValue": "90",
      "gatewayDictLabel": "",
      "gatewayDictCode": "471807606496563200",
      "noStationTreeResp": [
        {
          "frontId": "000",
          "typeDictValue": "5950",
          "typeDictLabel": "",
          "typeDictCode": "453008915757404160",
          "entities": []
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Don't spam phrases. Instead, show your attempts and effort. Give us the specific error you encountered so people can take a closer look.

Answer (score 0):

This answer assumes you have no more than one matching array element in each array.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $set: {
      "gatewayTreeResp": {
        $first: {      //convert the array to nested document by selecting one matching array element
          $filter: {
            input: "$gatewayTreeResp",
            cond: {$eq: ["$$this.gatewayDictValue", "90"]}  //filter the array elements
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      "gatewayTreeResp.noStationTreeResp": {
        $filter: {
          input: "$gatewayTreeResp.noStationTreeResp",
          cond: {$eq: ["$$this.typeDictValue","5950"]}      //filter the inner array elements
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      "gatewayTreeResp": ["$gatewayTreeResp"]               //convert the nested document back to array
    }
  }
])
```

[Demo](https://mongoplayground.net/p/K8r5Y1g-ADq)